# IOS 12.4.4 AVPlayer is not playing audio

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am trying to develop radio streaming app from URL audio using `AVPlayer` I was testing (simulator IOS 13.0 ) and everything was working.
issue is when I try to run physical device with IOS 12.4.4 nothing is working(playing)

this is what I did so far.

```
    let url = "http://radiostreaming"//streaming url
    var isPlaying = false;

    var player : AVPlayer!
    var playerItem : AVPlayerItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: url)!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        player.volume = 1.0
        player.rate = 1.0
        player.allowsExternalPlayback = true
        player.play()

}
```

any help please

Comment: did you get any error in logs?

Comment: no I am not getting any error

Comment: Where is `AVPlayerViewController` ??

Comment: I tried to print  `isPlaying` after  `player.play()` and it's true. I am also making `NowPlayingAnimation` after `player.play()` and its also working but till streaming is not playing

Comment: can you share actual streaming url you are using??

Comment: May your device in silent mode?  now it sounds silly but it happens :)